# how to separate the slides

Tags: javascript, html

[this is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxVfj.png)

how to separate it to different place like top left and bottom right something?

the dots of second slide can't run properly and it will display the dot of slide 1 also...

the next button of this two slide mix together already, when i click the next button at third picture, it will go to second slide but no move back to first picture ...

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides 1">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="special14-double-black.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides 1">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="images.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides 1">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="Taroball Shiruko.jpeg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 3</div>
        </div> <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center"> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides 2">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="Sesame Supreme.jpeg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides 2">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="Bestseller 'Cold'.jpeg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides 2">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="Bestseller 'Hot'.jpeg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption 3</div>
        </div> <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center"> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: are two of those images supposed to be the same ones?  Could that explain the part of the problem you describe about them not changing?  I am talking about this file: special14-double-black.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yandy. Your JavaScript code appears to be working but I see several problems.

1. You have two slideshows.  I am unsure why you have two slideshows at once.  Is there any reason for that?
2. Your images are not all different.  That could explain the problems you are describing switching between them (if I understand you correctly).
3. I got your slideshow code to work by removing one of the slideshows and structuring the logic you have to check if the slide goes out of the bounds of the index position of your slides like so:

```js
     if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
     else if (n < 1) 
     {slideIndex = (slides.length)}
```

4. You are missing an ending `</body>` tag also in your HTML.

I think that one of your biggest problems though is that you have both sets of controls (previous and next buttons/dots) targeting the same class name (mySlides), and it is moving through slides from both slideshows at once.

If you wanted, you definitely could have two separate slideshows, and one way to do so might be to give each slideshow different id selector names on the parent div (e.g. id='slideshow-container1', & id='slideshow-container2').  Then you might store the value of the parent container id (containing your slide show) when clicking the appropriate next/previous buttons.  Then do a check of which slideshow is the one that you need to shift slides on.

It is tough for me to understand what you are trying to accomplish aside from getting the slideshow to work.  Can you please elaborate and I or someone else will work to help you?  Also, can you edit your question to include a JavaScript tag because it is more than html that you need help with?

**EDIT**

@yandy if you want to do something similar to what you have already with two different slideshows, and assuming that you are only going to have 3 slides in each slideshow (as you have already stated in your responses), you could do something like the following example I am providing below.

I added comments to the JavaScript explaining each piece so I hope that makes sense to you.  I broke out portions of your showSlides function into more functions and added comments to all of them.

This is not exactly an ideal solution since the way you have done this is not how I would personally choose to code this, but I wanted to give you an example of how to make this work with what you already have.

If you want to learn more about how to do this in a better way, I recommend picking up a good book that covers the fundamentals of JavaScript like Eloquent JS (https://eloquentjavascript.net) or to read through the 'Get Started' book/chapters of the You Don't Know JS at their Github repo which you can access here:  https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/get-started/README.md

These books are excellent resources to learn more about JavaScript and to be able to understand how to make all sorts of useful and fun projects with it!

You also might do a search on your favorite search engine for a good tutorial on 'vanilla JavaScript slideshow tutorial'. I am not sure what resources you have already been looking at, but when posting to StackOverflow it is a good idea to include examples of code/tutorials you are following along with or trying to replicate & incorporate into your own project when asking a question.

```html
<body>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/207691/pexels-photo-207691.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1366942/pexels-photo-1366942.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1366944/pexels-photo-1366944.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption 3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="control">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, this)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, this)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>

    </div>

 <hr>

 <div class="slideshow-container">
    
  <div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/unsplash/moon.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/unsplash/astronaut.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/unsplash/bridge.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="control">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, this)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, this)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
  </div>

    </body>
    
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    
    //pass null on initial load which meets the first condition of the if statement in showSlides
    showSlides(slideIndex, null);
    
    //changed to pass elem (this in HTML above)
    function plusSlides(n, elem) {
    
     showSlides((slideIndex += n), elem);

    }
    
    //I have not tested this but it looks reasonable (if the dots are visible)
    function currentSlide(n) {
     showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
function showSlides(n, elem) {
    // var i;  commented this out because it is unnecessary
    
var slides;


//this is for the first initialization/first loading of the slide shows when you aren't passing anything as 'elem' (elem = null).
if(elem === null)
{
  
  slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  
    }
    else {
   //this is for when 'this' is passed into the showSlides function (in the HTML above)
  // get appropriate slide show regardless of which arrow controls are selected
   var parental = elem.parentNode;
   var outerParent = parental.parentNode;
  
  slides = outerParent.querySelectorAll('.mySlides');
   var dots = outerParent.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   
    }
    
    //call prevNext function passing n and slides
    prevNext(n, slides);
     
    //call slideDisplay function  
    slideDisplay(slides);

     //call dotActive function
     dotActive(dots);

     }
     
//new function to move between slides
function prevNext(n, slides){
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      else if (n < 1) 
     {slideIndex = (slides.length)}
}

//new function to display slides
     function slideDisplay(slides){
      for (i = 0; i < ((slides.length)); i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
     }
   
//this displays the appropriate slide in most instances
     slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  
  //this only applies to the second slide show when first loaded (since there are only three images)
     if (slides.length > 3) {
       
     slides[3].style.display = "block";
      }

     }

//this function controls which dots are active
     function dotActive(dots){
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
     }
       dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
     }
     
    </script>
```

Comment: 1. Yes. I'm trying to create two slideshows. But I wonder why it will combined to once?
2. After changed all the images to different, it have the same problem.
3. Yes, it can work if just one slideshow, but two can't. Is that i need to add the scripts you provides? 
4. thanks, maybe I miss out when copy.

Comment: If I have changed different id for each slideshow, should i also need to change scripts?
 OK so sorry, I added the tag. I just want to create two slideshows with 3 images each and put them at the different place of webpage, but that slideshows combines at once. I'm new in this so no sure what should I changed to get the output.

Comment: @yandy please see the edits I made above.  Hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: oh yes it help me. Thank you.

Comment: How about if I add animation to each slideshows to play both manual and automatic?  I have the problem which it only play on first slideshows but not all slideshows play at the same time.